# Nest objects in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hi I am working on creating a basic nest object structure in Rails and I am having some issues figuring out what direction to go in structuring things.

I want to have an object called Item related to an object called Product.

Here are the models:

```
class CreateItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description      
      t.decimal :price
      t.string :image_file_name
      t.integer :inventory

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Item always has 1 product associated with it and potentially the Product could have many referencing Items.

What I am having problems with is figuring out how to access these both within an html list easily. I know how to get access to the Item or the Product within a list, but I can figure out how to combine them within the same list and get the item.name and associated product.price in my html.erb.

Can anyone help or point me to a good example online of a similar structure in rails MVC where the model, controller and view have this all plugged in so I can see it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your your model definitions, you'll want to set up the one-to-many association.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

and

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Given you you have instance of `Item` (i.e. a record from the database) stored in, let's call it, `myitem`, you'll use the following to get the `price` of the associated `Product`.

```
myitem.product.price
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error saying something along the lines of "undefined method `product' for #<Item:0x3f33660>"

Comment: I just updated the answer to reflect the definition of the relationships in your model.

Comment: That was it. I had something wrong in the model class.
Thank you!

Comment: you had `belongs_to :products` (plural), didn't you?  Very common mistake, I still do that from time to time. ;-)